# Drupal - Prohibit css files in specific pages

Tags: javascript, css, drupal, drupal-7

I am using a custom theme in Drupal and the jquery and bootstrap version in pretty outdated. Old pages in are in that version but I want to design few new pages where I want to include the latest version of bootstrap and jquery. Now whenever I design a new page, Drupal itself adds certain wrappers to it and includes the previous bootstrap, jquery version in the aggregate js file. I just want it to be plain html and not include any other css/js files or make any other modifications.

I have added CSS, JS files in link and script tags. And few elements also have inline css. I just want it to render as a simple HTML page

Currently this is my theme.inc file

```
foreach ($stylesheets as $stylesheet) {
  drupal_add_css($stylesheet, array('group' => CSS_THEME, 'every_page' => TRUE, 'media' => $media));
}
```

I want to restrict this for certain pages. Any leads?

Answer (score 0):

You could try hook_css_alter() and hook_js_alter() like it is suggestsed here:

[Drupal 7 override jquery js file in custom theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22900307/drupal-7-override-jquery-js-file-in-custom-theme#22931513)

In your node preprocess function in template.php in your theme. But I don't know if you could limit this to just some nodes, or pages.